# Call web service running on Parallels from iPhone connected via USB

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, networking, parallels

I can request a web service running on IIS Express/Parallels from Mac OS with...

```
http://windows:57239/api/hello
```

This works fine from the iPhone simulator, but not from an iPhone device connected via USB, when debugging in XCode.

Is it possible to make this work? I would like to debug my API with in-app purchases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my Parallels instance to [Bridged](http://kb.parallels.com/4948) networking mode and let the Wifi's DHCP assign an IP address to it. Then I used this IP address from the iPhone app.

Not entirely satisfying because the IP will vary, but its very cool having an iPhone trigger a break point in Visual Studio running on a virtual instance of Windows.